# Using Philips-Hue Obj-C in Swift Project

Tags: objective-c, swift, philips-hue

I am a complete beginner when it comes to coding (except for web) but wanted to start with it. So I bought a philips hue set which I wanted to control via Swift2. I started a online Swift2 course which helped me to get started (still beginner) and so I hoped HUE will help me to learn coding Swift2 in a playful way.

But: The API provided by Philips is in Obj-C which absolutely confuses me. There should be a way to integrate it into a Swift project but as I said.. as a beginner I can't manage to do it (http://www.developers.meethue.com/documentation/apple-sdk).

After downloading the example I was able to run it on my lights which worked fine, but I am not able to understand nor change the code.
I googled and tried to find an example where someone included it into Swift so that I can start playing with the lights and start using what I learned so far.

Because there is so little information out there I came here, hoping you guys could help me getting started - how would a project look like, so that I can use the obj-C parts (especially connecting to the bridge) in my swift project? Is there somewhere a demo out there I wasn't able to find?
Sorry for my "unprofessional" question but it would mean a lot to me to get started with this :)

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Swift and Obj-C are interchangeable, as apple says:

> Objective-C and Swift files can coexist in a single project, whether
> the project was originally an Objective-C or Swift project. You can
> simply add a file of the other language directly to an existing
> project. This natural workflow makes creating mixed-language app and
> framework targets as straightforward as creating an app or framework
> target written in a single language. [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

---

To create a header bridge file follow these steps

1. Add a new file to Xcode (File > New > File), then select “Source” and click “Header File“.
2. Name your file “YourProjectName-Bridging-Header.h”.  Example: In my app Station, the file is named “Station-Bridging-Header”.
3. Create the file.
4. Navigate to your project build settings and find the “Swift Compiler – Code Generation” section.  You may find it faster to type in “Swift Compiler” into the search box to narrow down the results.  Note: If you don’t have a “Swift Compiler – Code Generation” section, this means you probably don’t have any Swift classes added to your project yet.  Add a Swift file, then try again.
5. Next to “Objective-C Bridging Header” you will need to add the name/path of your header file.  If your file resides in your project’s root folder simply put the name of the header file there.  Examples:  “ProjectName/ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h” or simply “ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h”.
6. Open up your newly created bridging header and import your Objective-C classes using #import statements.  Any class listed in this file will be able to be accessed from your swift classes.
   [Reference](http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/)

Once you have created your bridge file and hooked it up, you can place your Obj-C import statements in there (`#import <HueSDK_iOS/HueSDK.h>`) and then use the Obj-C functions in swift.

If their docs are bad I would suggest doing a really quick intro to Obj-C, just so that you can easily translate the sample project to your new project.